# is there an easy way for a domain to get session info from subdomain?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, session, session-cookies

When it comes to **cookies**, I know I can set it this way:

```
`setcookie('info', json_encode(array('foo' => bar, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", ".example.com");`
```

so even if the code runs on `www.example.com`, it will still allow `react.example.com` to read the info.

I want to do the opposite, and have my react app, create and store session info:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('react_info', `${user.info}`);
```

then have a link on the app which redirects user to a php page on `www.example.com`.

On this page, the result of:

```
 `var_dump($_SESSION['react_info']);`
```

is `NULL`, because seems like the session storage is only made on `react.example.com`.

What are the ways to handle this?

Also If the rationale is security concern, then why is it possible to easily share cookies across sub domains, but it's not possible to do so with server side sessions?

Comment: `sessionStorage` is client-side, and doesn't have anything to do with PHP's `$_SESSION` in the first place.

Comment: oh dear. is there a way then to create session info that can be read with PHP $_SESSION, using javascript?

Comment: Only by letting PHP itself store it into the session in the first place. So you could use JS to make a background request to a PHP script, and have that store whatever info you need to pass ...

Comment: but if I have the JS make a background request that is crossing subdomains, I must change my server config to allow this, as by default browsers see it as security risk, right?

Comment: Yes, but if your javascript files and PHP files are being served from the same domain/origin, then you don't need to do anything.